# Example of a vector space in Linear Algebra of W.Greub

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I was reading linear algebra from Webner Greub but I don't understand in this example what field the vector space is in, that  is, is where $\lambda$?

Comment: It is in $\Gamma$, whatever that is.

Comment: any field serves, I mean, any field complies

Answer (score 0):

The quick response is that $\lambda$ is also in the field $\Gamma$. Thus, you can check that the axioms for $\Gamma^n$ to be a vector space, over any of your favorite fields, are guaranteed.